# Exchange has closed form also in DFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, computational-physics, density-functional-theory, exchange-interaction

I have heard from my lecturer that in the context of DFT, the exact exchange energy has a known closed form, even though it is not a functional of the density. I have been trying to figure out what this it's form is.

In either DFT or HF we want to solve $h_i \psi_i = \varepsilon_i \psi_i$ with hamiltonian $H = \sum_i h_i$. The form of $h_i$ is different between the two methods:

$$
h_i = - \frac{1}{2} \nabla^2 + V_\text{H} + V_\text{ext}  + V_\text{x} \qquad \text{in HF}
\\
h_i = - \frac{1}{2} \nabla^2 + V_\text{H} + V_\text{ext}  + V_\text{x} +  V_\text{c} \qquad \text{in DFT}
$$
In HF, minimizing the energy provides the following term for the exchange energy
$$
E_\text{x} = - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} \int \frac{ \phi_{n_i}^*(s')\phi_{n_j}(s')\phi_{n_j}^*(s)\phi_{n_i}(s) }{|r - r'|}ds ds'.
$$
I know this is not a functional of the density, and therefore it doesn't fit into the philosophy of DFT, but in case I wanted to add exchage to DFT regardless of the computational cost, would I simply plug in this expression and get the correct answer?

Comment: In the Kohn-Sham DFT, the exchange energy is defined in terms of the KS orbitals, i.e., not the same orbitals that you get in HF, because they are not optimized to get the lowest energy, but the best density. This means that the exchange in DFT differs from the exchange in HF, and mixing them **without care** would provide less quantitative calculations. Moreover, HF exchange is contained in parametrized hybrid functionals like B3LYP.

Comment: 6 months is long to not get an answer, you can copy and paste here: https://materials.stackexchange.com now that Materials.SE is live.